# How do you use a CombinedConfiguration to override a default configuration?

Tags: java, apache-commons-config

When adding configurations to a [CombinedConfiguration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/CombinedConfiguration.html) (from Apache Commons Configuration 2), how do you specify that one configuration overrides another?

For example, say I have a default configuration and a user configuration. If I want the user to override the default, how do I setup the the combined configuration?

```
XMLConfiguration defaultConfig = ...;
XMLConfiguration userConfig = ...;

CombinedConfiguration config = new CombinedConfiguration();
config.addConfiguration(defaultConfig);
config.addConfiguration(userConfig);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the which `NodeCombiner` passed to the constructor of the `CombinedConfiguration` class. For example if `OverrideCombiner` is used first item added to the configuration will take precedence over other nodes. If you call default constructor of `CombinedConfiguration`, `UnionCombiner` will be used.

[OverrideCombiner Docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/tree/OverrideCombiner.html)

[MergeCombiner Docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/tree/MergeCombiner.html)

[UnionCombiner Docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/tree/UnionCombiner.html)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use an [OverrideCombiner](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/tree/OverrideCombiner.html), and the configurations need to be added from highest to lowest priority.

```
CombinedConfiguration config = new CombinedConfiguration(new OverrideCombiner());
config.addConfiguration(userConfig);
config.addConfiguration(defaultConfig);
```